# Unity not ignoring button click in "Ignore Raycast" layer

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, raycasting

I created a new scene to test **'Ignore Raycast'** layer functionality in unity 2018.2.6f1. The scene is just a UI button with a log script attached. When I change the button layer to **'Ignore Raycast'**, the button still works. Do all the buttons behave this way until we manually turn off 'Raycast Target' & 'Interactable' checkboxes in Image and Button components?

I want to know the dependency between the 3 options 'Ignore Raycast', 'Raycast Target' & 'Interactable'.

[image: Button inspector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Interactable` is easy. If the Graphic Raycaster finds an event (mouse over, click, mouse off, etc) on the button, does it react to those events? If `Interactable` is true, then it will.

The other two need some explanation.

Layers are used to handle collision with Unity's **Physics** raycasting.

The `Ignore Raycast` layer is just like any other layer, but is intended to be typically ignored by Physics raycasts. **It's up to the code that creates the Physics raycast to decide if colliders on objects in the `Ignore Raycast` layer are actually ignored.** For instance, if you create a Physics raycast with a mask of `Physics.IgnoreRaycastLayer`, then it will only collide with colliders of objects in the `Ignore Raycast` layer.

However, again, that setting deals with Physics raycasts

`Raycast Target` deals with the Unity **Graphic** Raycaster, which is how Unity  handles interaction with UI elements (by default). The Graphic Raycaster is totally independent from Physics raycast, and how it masks with layers.  Instead of layers, Graphic Raycaster allows for control over collision in two ways.

The first of these ways is something called `UI.GraphicRaycaster.BlockingObjects` which makes the raycast stop when it hits 2d objects or 3d objects, both, or neither.

The second of these ways is where `Ignore Raycast` comes into play.

The `Raycast Target` of a ui element determines if raycasts that collide with that element stop at that element, so things below it don't also get interacted with. If `Raycast Target` is enabled, then when you mouse over or click a button or whatever, it will respond however it is configured to do so, *but* anything below the button *won't* have that interaction event.

For example, suppose you want to create a popup that can be interacted with in a way where they aren't clicking on buttons underneath the popup accidentally. You would want to enable `Raycast Target` on the popup and its buttons and so on in that case.

TL;DR:

- `Interactable` determines if the button is enabled or disabled on its own.
- `Raycast Target` determines if the button blocks buttons covered up by it from doing things.
- `Ignore Raycast` determines if **Physics** raycasts ignore colliders attached to it by default.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, it helped a lot!. So, instead of worrying about `Ignore raycast layer`, can I use a `canvas group` to turn off raycasting of UI elements? Does it have a positive performance impact?

Comment: there is some advice about raycast her https://create.unity3d.com/Unity-UI-optimization-tips . `canvas group` shouldn't change much about performance. better things would be to break up the canvas into smaller pieces and to turn off `raycast target` on as many things as you can get away with.